# What is this property of honey called

Tags: single-word-requests

When you drizzle honey, it becomes a thin stream that goes all "jiggly" as it hits your sandwich. I believe this is due to the way that the long molecules align as the liquid falls and becomes thinner.

I suspect there is a word for that property. It's not viscosity - that is what makes a liquid resist shear. This is a "temporary alignment that results in transient elastic behavior".

I would have thought there's a word for that, but my Google Fu is failing me. Any scientists here that are also awesome with words?

Comment: also answered here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/222004/explanation-of-the-liquid-rope-coil-effect

Comment: @lbf thanks. The term “liquid rope effect” definitely opens up a world of useful links.

Comment: Just to throw a word in,  you might consider "gelatinous" and describe something as a "gelatinous fluid" ..  I think that might capture a readers visual imagery well.  They'd imagine both thick and prone to sort of hold some form before it gradually settled in.  If you are looking for this sort of answer I'd right it up .. it is not any official or common term.

Comment: @Tom22 no, gelatinous is not the word I was thinking of but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Better explanation is here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/245948/patterns-in-falling-viscous-fluids.  But there is no single word for it, at least as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

**viscosity**   [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/viscosity)

> The resistance of a substance to flow. A substance that can flow easily has a low viscosity. A substance that cannot flow easily has a high viscosity.

[image]

As in:

> Honey has a high viscosity.

And fluid dynamics of honey:  [Journal of Fluid Dynamics](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c937/0cb642eff2e677e6c9ac25b04eb304b942fb.pdf)

> A thin ‘*rope*’ of **viscous** fluid falling from a sufficient height
>   onto a surface forms a series of regular coils.

[image: the physics of] err ... a little above my pay grade.  But herein may lie the secrets to a space 'warp drive' lol!

Comment: Viscous is the property that makes honey "thick" or water "thin" (in a sense), but it doesn't describe the "jiggly" behavior the OP was asking about.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the term you're looking for is the **liquid rope-coil effect.**

While there is no definition entry in any  in any form, it appears to be an accepted term among those who study physics.

This blurb from [Scientific American](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/dribbling-fluids-coil-around-like-ropes/) writes:

> [This] thin stream of falling honey does not approach the toast directly, but instead builds up a whirling helical structure. In the late 1950s the resemblance to a pile of coiled rope led the first investigators of this phenomenon, George Barnes and Richard Woodcock, to call it the **liquid rope-coil effect.**

Hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

'**Non-Newtonian**' is the scientific description given to some fluids which have specific behaviour and properties like those described by the OP.

The behaviour of such fluids is not *just* a matter of viscosity :

> Many salt solutions and molten polymers are non-Newtonian fluids, as are many commonly found substances such as ketchup, custard, toothpaste, starch suspensions, maizena, **honey**, paint, blood, and shampoo.
>
> Although the concept of viscosity is commonly used in fluid mechanics to characterize the shear properties of a fluid, it can be inadequate to describe non-Newtonian fluids.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Newtonian_fluid)

Further reference supplied by @JJJ :

> what we really need physicists to focus on is the mystery of why strands of sweet, sticky honey can get so long and thin as they drip without actually breaking.

[The Physics of Dripping Honey](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/cocktail-party-physics/an-ti-ci-pa-tion-the-physics-of-dripping-honey/)

Comment: _"In a non-Newtonian fluid, the viscosity changes in response to an applied strain or shearing force, thereby straddling the boundary between liquid and solid behavior."_ from [Scientific American](https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/cocktail-party-physics/an-ti-ci-pa-tion-the-physics-of-dripping-honey/). Feel free to add a quote from that in your answer (I think it's interesting and relevant).

Comment: ah ... take a look at the **Fluid Dynamics** link in my wonderful answer :)

Comment: Sorry @lbf TL;DR

Comment: @lbf that paper doesn't mention the (non-)Newtonian part, right? I think all 3 answer look at it from a different (but equally interesting / relevant) angle.

Comment: indeed!  who wud have thunk it?

Comment: Professor Non-Newton has a lot to answer for.

Comment: It's great that you wrote this answer - but after researching non-Newtonian fluids a bit more carefully I think the reason honey is listed there is because it can "set" and yet become liquid when you stir it (thixotropic). That qualifies it as non-Newtonian but it might not what makes it coil. I'm starting to believe that maybe it's plain old viscosity after all, but that's not really satisfying. For now I will leave no answer accepted... maybe another suggestion appears. But I've given you the upvote - thanks for your time.

Comment: @Floris The thixotropicity is what gives it the 'body' in order to form a shape. And thixotropicity is a feature of non-Newtonians.